# MongoDB $addField and $indexOfArray in Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to implement a custom sort with MongoDB and Spring Data according to Asya Kamsky's [post](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/using-34-aggregation-to-return-documents-in-same-order-as-in-expression):

```
List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();

operations.add(Aggregation.addFields().addField("scorrrz")
        .withValueOfExpression("{ \"$indexOfArray\" : [ [\"John\", \"Bill\"], \"$name\" ] }").build());
```

When I try to execute this, I get:

```
ERROR a.insurance.misc.ErrorAttributes - /api/v1/insurance/opportunity/all
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [{ "$indexOfArray" : [ ["John", "Bill"], "$name" ] }] @29: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'comma(,)'
```

Is this not the right syntaxt? How can this be done with Spring Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Collection<String> nameList = Arrays.asList("John", "Bill");

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                    addFields()
                     .addField("scorrrz").withValue(arrayOf(nameList).indexOf("$name"))
                     .build()
);
```

The aggregation's projection is an `$addFields` stage with a `$indexOfArray` aggregation array operation. This will return a field `scorrrz`, and it will have index value *or* `-1` when there is no match. This ran okay with Spring Boot v2.3.10 and MongoDB v4.2.8.

The run this aggregation pass the pipeline `agg` to the `MongoTemplate#aggregate` method.

Comment: hey can you help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74533232/spring-boot-mongodb-aggregation-add-filed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate `$indexOfArray` using the array from the DB document itself, you need the aggregate pipeline to perform the calculation instead of the Java code.

Here is my solution

```
Aggregation.addFields()
    .addField("scorrrz")
    .withValueOf(MongoExpression.create(" $indexOfArray : [ [ 'John', 'Bill' ], '$name' ]"))
    .build()
```

This creates the following pipeline stage

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "scorrrz": {
            "$indexOfArray": [
                [
                    "John",
                    "Bill"
                ],
                "$name"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```