# How to code "generatedDate: new Date()" with Spring Data MongoDB Java API?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need help with [Spring Data Java API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/). I am writing aggregation pipeline for the report. The last stage is "$project" where I set the data for output. In Mongodb shell the pipeline works just fine but I can't find the way to code "generatedDate: new Date()" with Spring Data SDK for MongoDB.
Here is how the "$project" should look like:

```
{$project: {
  coach: {
    firstName: '$coach.firstName',
    lastName: '$coach.lastName',
    employeeId: '$coach._id'
  },
  patient: {
    firstName: '$patientContact.patient.firstName',
    lastName: '$patientContact.patient.lastName',
    contactId: '$patientContact._id'
  },
  customerName: '$patientContact.organization.name',
  coachingSummary: 1,
  formCreatedDate: 1,
  generatedDate: new Date() //<<--- This is what I want 
}}
```

I want the server to generate [new Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/Date/) instance and return it in the response.

Here is my Java code for this aggregation stage:

```
ProjectionOperation finalProject = project("coachingSummary", "formCreatedDate")
    .and("$patientContact.organization.name").as("customerName")
    .and("coach")
    .nested(Fields.from(
            Fields.field("firstName", "coach.firstName"),
            Fields.field("lastName", "coach.lastName"),
            Fields.field("employeeId", "coach._id")
    ))
    .and("patient")
    .nested(Fields.from(
            Fields.field("firstName", "patientContact.patient.firstName"),
            Fields.field("lastName", "patientContact.patient.lastName"),
            Fields.field("contactId", "patientContact._id")
    ))
    .and("<SOMETHING_GOES_HERE>").as("generatedDate");//<<-- How to code it?
```

Comment: You can try using the `addFieldsOperation` (instead of `ProjectionOperation`), which allows adding new fields with derived values.

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you Prasad. This is what I do right now and I have to pass Date from Java to Mongo. Although I would like to know how to code "generatedDate: new Date()" with Spring Data MongoDB Java API. Maybe it is not possible but maybe there is a way and somebody can show it.

Comment: Here is an example usage of addFieldsOperation (note that $addFields can be substituted for $project in MongoDB Aggregation queries): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907801/mongodb-addfield-and-indexofarray-in-spring-data

Comment: @prasad_ I know about $addFields https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/. Although, how you code in Java the following code:
{$add: {
  generatedDate: new Date()
}}

Important: the date should be provided by the Mongodb, not by Java.

Please read more about MongoDB Date type: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/Date/

Comment: You can try using the MongoDB aggregation system variable [NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW)